# Deploy an application using dll files to IIS on a VM

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines

I hope I am posting this in the correct forum, but to me at least, it seemed that the focus was more on deployment.

I am currently stuck after having successfully refactored an application by extracting certain responsibilities into
class libraries (language: C#, .NET 4.8).

The application is hooked up to Azure CI builds using Azure DevOps, deploying the application to an IIS on a VM. Pipelines are triggered upon commit.

The pipeline looks roughly like this:

- `NuGet restore`
- `Build Solution`
- `Test Assemblies (Visual Studio Tests)`
- `Publish symbols path`
- `Publish Artifact`

The `.dll` files are located in a dedicated folder within the application.
I am referencing the `.dll` files in the application and have already changed their property `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.
When building the application on my local machine, the required custom `.dll` files are being copied to the `bin` folder as expected.
However, when analysing the deployment logs, I noticed that the custom `.dll` files are not being updated / copied.

How can I make sure that the custom `.dll` files are deployed properly (same as the standard `.ddl` files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no other way than creating NuGet packages from those `.dll` files required for the build, as this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804770/include-local-dll-in-azure-devops-pipeline/65805424#65805424) points out.